# Why did Luffy ring the bell 16 times?

Tags: one-piece

I'm confused as to why Luffy rung the bell 16 times. A navy member said it's a declaration of war whereas a pirate said it's about the change of an era. Can someone please explain what exactly is the reason behind it??

Comment: Just watch episode 511 for complete description .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bell is called the [Ox-Bell](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ox_Bell).

What does the ringing of the bell signify?

> The ringing of the bell signifies the end of one year and the beginning of another. It is rung eight times to give thanks for the old year, and another eight times to welcome the new year. If it is rung twice, it signifies some sort of disaster or distress.

**How others interpreted 16 rings:**

> Lieutenant Commander Brandnew of the Marines analyzed it as a declaration of war, and Killer of the Kid Pirates interpreted the meaning of it as the end of one era and the beginning of another.

[image: The Ox Bell]

**The real reason behind it:**

> Luffy's ringing of the bell was only a distraction, along with his other actions, so nobody in the world outside of the Straw Hat Pirates would notice the real message; in the picture of Luffy after ringing the Ox Bell, a mark is seen on his arm that reads 3D2Y with the 3D crossed out, representing the amount of time the crew would be separated.

Comment: 8 chimes always indicate the end/beginning of a year/era as you said. That's why the others interpreted it as if Luffy was saying Whitebeard's era has ended, but mine will now begin. So towards the government that's a war-statement, while it is a challenge towards the other rookies.

Answer (score 0):

16 bells, rung on a ships bell by the youngest crew member at midnight on the 31st December, ring out the old, ring in the new, as 8 bells signify the end of a watch and the beginning of another one, so it is with the years end/ beginning.

Comment: This symbol is already explained in the first answer.  Plus your answer does not explain what that has to do with One Piece. The calendar year does not end at that point of the story... so why does Luffy ring the bell?